# Does anyone know what this notation means: $n^{\underline{n}}$?

Tags: combinatorics, notation

This is what I don't understand: $n^{\underline{n}}$

This is in a Combinatorics paper I am working my way through, and n is some natural number. I **think** that it should mean $n!$

The full question is "True or False: The number of permutations of n objects is $n^{\underline{n}}$"

Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Try `$n^{\underline{n}}$` instead of inserting an image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I imagine it's the [falling factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pochhammer_symbol&oldid=588958179#Alternate_notations):

$$ x^{\underline{n}} = x (x-1)^{\underline{n-1}} \qquad x^{\underline{0}} = 1$$

In particular, $n^{\underline{n}} = n!$ for any nonnegative integer $n$, as you conjectured.

Comment: Thanks for confirming! So how would one calculate $n^{\underline{k}}$ for some $0\leq k \leq n$ ?

EDIT: Is this just $n!/k!$ ?

Comment: The other way: $n! / (n-k)!$. But only when $n$ is an integer at least as large as $k$; there is some point to the fact it immediately makes sense when $n$ is an arbitrary real number, or even that $x^{\underline{k}}$ is a degree $k$ polynomial in the indeterminate variable $x$.